# Laravel Call to a member function isValid() on null

Tags: php, laravel

In my project users can upload stuff and attach an image.
I have a controller where I do a isValid check on the file input. Everything works great as long as you select a file. When I don't select a file I get this error

```
Call to a member function isValid() on null
```

On this line of code:

```
if (Input::file('image')->isValid())
```

The error is obvious since I don't select an image but I actually have no idea how I can fix this.

If anyone can help I'd be very happy :)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `hasFile()`: `if (Input::hasFile('image'))`

Comment: @Rifki  thought about this but don't want to use this method, since I am validating a form. I just want an error message to be shown like "please upload a file" or something

Comment: Then you need a validation rule for that no need to use `if` statement, something like `'image' => 'mimes:jpeg,bmp,png'`

Answer (score 4):

> First you need to check if your request is containing that file / input or not.

**Determining If A File Was Uploaded**

```
if (Request::hasFile('image'))
{
    /*Determining If An Uploaded File Is Valid*/
    if (Request::file('image')->isValid())
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Just for your info also make sure you are getting file while posting.
Add attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your HTML Form Element.

You can use any of Input and Request facade.
Input class is also referencing to `\Illuminate\Http\Request` in laravel

Comment: But this way I can't use the error messages I use in my Request file for example if a title is shorter than 3 characters an error message is shown that the title must be longer than 3 characters I want to use the same method to validate the file input

Comment: so add a validation rule for that field

Answer (score 2):

add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form